# Establishing the chapters in a book, given the function get_chapter(page_number)

Tags: algorithm, search

I have a function called get_chapter which takes a page number as an argument and returns a unique string representing the chapter the page belongs to, for example "The Story Continues". If I enter a page number outside the book, I am returned an empty string.

The first page is page 0. Chapters are a set of consecutive pages and a given page belongs to only one chapter.

What algorithm would you recommend which can identify the page ranges for each chapter? Any estimate as to how many times I would need to call get_chapter?

I need to limit calls to get_chapter as much as possible. Chapters average 50000 pages. And there are approximately 30000000 pages in the book! Not sure how many chapters exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prime a list of chapter boundaries with the first page.

Set `low` to the first page and `high` to the last.

If `get_chapter(low) == get_chapter(high)`, then you know everything in that range is in the same chapter, and you don't need to divide it further.

If `get_chapter(low) != get_chapter(high)` and `low + 1 == high`, then you have adjacent pages in different chapters.  That means a new chapter begins at high.

If `get_chapter(low) != get_chapter(high)` and `low + 1 < high`, then there is at least one chapter boundary in the range.  Split the range by choosing a page in middle and *recursively* descend both of the new ranges (low:middle and middle:high).

If you added the boundaries to a list as you found them, and you always recursed the lower subrange first, then you're done.  Otherwise, sort the boundary list.

I believe the run-time complexity is approximately O(number_of_chapters * log_2(average_chapter_size)), but that's a gut-check and not a thorough analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

1. Call get_chapter on the last page to find out how many chapters there are.
2. Work out the average size of a chapter, and call get_chapter for the estimated middle of each chapter.
3. Use binary search between adjacent chapters to find the boundary.
4. Modify for large or small chapters where the initial estimates from step 2 span two chapters or fall in the same large chapter.

The average number of calls is something like n + log2(s), where n is the number of chapters and s is the average size of a chapter in pages.

Comment: As mentioned, get_chapter returns text like "The Story Continues". So there is no simple way of establishing the number of chapters.

Comment: Then you are going to have to check a lot of pages because a chapter can be as short as a single page.  Perhaps a binary search to find two pages in the same chapter and then expand outwards from there to find the boundaries.  If there are 5,000 pages per chapter, then you can direct the first cut of the binary search accordingly.